# Kendo Grid DropDown Filter different versions of kendo.all.min.js not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have follow [jsfiddle 2013.2.716/js/kendo.all.min.js](http://jsfiddle.net/0ydturzb/167/) and the filter text works correctly with the 2013 version

```
var dropDown = gridEl.find(".k-toolbar label input[type=search]").bind('propertychange keyup input paste', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (value) {
    grid.dataSource.filter({
      field: labelFieldName,
      operator: "contains",
      value: value
    });
  } else {
    grid.dataSource.filter({});
  }
});
```

but if i use the version 2015 it not work
[jsfiddle 2015.2.624/js/kendo.all.min.js](http://jsfiddle.net/0ydturzb/169/) 
how I can solve this in the keyup event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replace the class name `.k-toolbar` with `.k-grid-toolbar`

e.g.

```
var dropDown = gridEl.find(".k-grid-toolbar label input[type=search]").bind('propertychange keyup input paste', function() {
  var value = $(this).val();
  if (value) {
    grid.dataSource.filter({
      field: labelFieldName,
      operator: "contains",
      value: value
    });
  } else {
    grid.dataSource.filter({});
  }
});
```